# Unfavoriting favorited jobs should reduce favorite count and fadeOut()?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Once you build up more then 3 favorites you are given a link to view all your favorite jobs.  As you unfavorite them they should but currently don't reduce the favorite count number at the top and also don't go away.

For making them go away it would be nice to simply do a `$(this).closest('div').fadeOut();` as to get rid of the actual favorite div entirely.  Or simply hide it.

The number at the top as mentioned also does not update:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we're re-using the search view as a way to list favorites, but as you point out, it doesn't behave the way a list of favorites should behave. We'll get a fix out for this soon, thanks!

Comment: Effin nice...looks great, love the jquery effect, that's what I'm talking about!  Nice job.